# How to connect Sharepoint API with my web service (C#)

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint

I would like to connect Sharepoint API with my web service (C#)

Can I create web service to post, like, comment, get notification or other activities from Sharepoint 2013?

If yes, How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

if you like to interact with SharePoint using C# I would recomend using the "SharePoint Client Object Model"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094(v=office.14).aspx

This way it is very easy to interact using SharePoint.

Regards